# Django admin url requesting username password in browser

Tags: django-admin

While um giving in my Django Admin URL address

An authentication pop up window is coming and asking for username and password
I am not understanding what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter the username and password you specified when you ran `syncdb`